# Where did the USS Leeds get its name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Recently, I asked a question about the ships in the intro for *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*. I learned of the *Nebula*-class starship called the USS *Leeds* (shown docked at the station in the Season 4 opening credits).

What is the inspiration behind the name? After doing some research, I found that there are various cities named Leeds, but they don't seem to be connected to exploration in any way that I noticed. Is the ship named after a person, or is it really named after the city?

[image]

Comment: Most likely named for the city, or for an earlier vessel named for the city. It is a common enough source for vessel names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Historical" ship names, are a common thing in Starfleet (the Enterprise NCC-1701 was named for the US aircraft carrier - though this was retconned in-universe to be in honour of the first space shuttle - which had been so named following a letter writing campaign of Star Trek fans - and then retconned again to account for the NX-01). However, while there has been an [HMS Leeds](http://www.naval-history.net/xGM-Chrono-11US-HMS_Leeds.htm), it does not seem to be all that notable (just another clapped out old destroyer in WWII which never saw any real action since it seems to have spent most of the war under repair).

I've tried to find if there has been any significant astronomer or scientist named Leeds, which is also a common source for ship names in Starfleet (Curie, Darwin, Pascal) - other than an archaeologist and paleontologist, I couldn't find anyone suitable.

Lastly, I tried to see if anyone involved in DS9 production had the surname Leeds (sometimes happens). Couldn't find anything.

However, Memory Beta (incredibly unreliable source) flatly states that the ship is named for the City of Leeds. Given that there are other ships name for cities (Alnwick - another north of England town - and Bozemann in Montana), this is the most plausible explanation.

Comment: There has been an HMS Leeds (one of the destroyers that changed hands in the "Destroyers for Bases Agreement" between the UK and the US in WW2), but still a second hand destroyer without any special history seems to be an unlikely namesake for a Federation ship.

Comment: http://www.naval-history.net/xGM-Chrono-11US-HMS_Leeds.htm - Part of the "Town" class of ships.

Comment: It is slightly possible the starship Bozeman is named after John Bozeman, a pioneer and explorer who founded the town of Bozeman, Montana and the bloody Bozeman Trail to Montana. The star trek encyclopedia says that it was named after the town, but it is not totally canonical so perhaps the ship was named after the explorer in the fictional universe of Star Trek.

Comment: @M.A.Golding show writer/runner Brannon Braga is from Bozeman - I think that makes the link to the town stronger, but explorers and pioneers are also used for ship names, so you could be right - Braga might have mentioned it at a convention.

Comment: Sir Patrick Stewart is from a small town near Leeds in West Yorkshire. That could be another explanation for why it would be named after the city.

Comment: @HorusKol Brannon Braga may have wanted ship named after his hometown in real life, but that doesn't mean that the ship was named after the town of Bozeman instead of John Bozeman in the fictional world of Star Trek.  If I become a star Trek producer and order a starship named after Windsor Ave. in Cape May, New Jersey, where my family had a summer house, Starfleet might name the USS Windsor after the English town, the castle, or the dynasty, in the fictional world of Star Trek.

Comment: @HorusKol  The only starfleet USS Alnwick is from a video game and thus not totally canon.  And it seems to me that a starship Alnwick might as likely be named after Alnwick Castle, like HMS Alnwick Castle, as Alnwick town.